# Locking a WMS layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, print-composer

When I switch between layout view and print composer view, the generation of my WMS layer appears to change, specifically, the text is barely readable. I assume the call for the WMS layer is a larger bounding box for the print composer.

Is there any way to 'lock' the  layer so it appears the same in layout view and print composer?

[image: Layout veiw]

[image: Print composer]

Comment: Your WMS doesn't allow the setting of a DPI - so you need to set your DPI to 96 (I think, or possibly 72) to make the scale correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue recently.

The work around is to Export the Existing Map Canvas as a Geo-referenced Image at x~3 Scale then bring that back in as a raster image.

**Project > Import/Export > Export Map to Image... > Change the scale to be 3 times larger that the scale you want to replicate > Pick a resolution > Save**

In my case, the scale of the wms layer was at **1:9000** so I exported my image to be at **1:27000**.
[image]

Here is a comparison of the image to the wms in the same area, as you can see the image appears the same as the wms:
This image can be used in the print composer.
[image]

Comment: This is a clever work-around.   But the OP got me wondering if the difference between the layout and composer views is a bug or is intentional.  If intentional, what is the rational?